In subiquity, where is apport imported from?
I'm trying to run make dryrun and getting the following error:
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
  return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
  exec(code, run_globals)
File "/root/workspace/subiquity/subiquity/__main__.py", line 6, in <module>
  sys.exit(main())
File "/root/workspace/subiquity/subiquity/cmd/tui.py", line 88, in main
  from subiquity.client.client import SubiquityClient
File "/root/workspace/subiquity/subiquity/client/client.py", line 32, in <module>
  from subiquity.common.errorreport import ErrorReporter
File "/root/workspace/subiquity/subiquity/common/errorreport.py", line 27, in <module>
  import apport
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apport'

I found this file on my file system:
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/apport.py

But that python3 is version 3.8, which is incompatible with the current code base. I installed and made a virtual environment for Python 3.9.
I tried

uninstalling and reinstalling python3-apport
pip install apport
uninstall and reinstall of cloud-init
pip install cloudinit

